# Azure media service Transcript generation

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have a requirement to generate transcripts of my videos when I upload it to azure blob in my c# function app. we already have one media service version 2. which we use for video encoding , this uses CloudMediaContext object to create context and job.
i could not find a way to add transform job to CloudMediaContext object. i have only seen examples over internet of adding transform using IAzureMediaServicesClient object.

Do i need to upgrade my media service from v2 to v3 ? but with this i will have to migrate my existing code and assets too , or do we have option of adding transform in V2 as well ?

Comment: i am bit new to azure so please forgive me if my understanding is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if you have an existing app on the Media Services v2 API, you should spend the time (hopefully minimal) upgrading it to the v3 API very soon.  The v2 API is not getting any newer features and does not have the latest speech to text models and transcription support.

Transforms were introduced in V3 API and also introduced a new basic "audio analyzer" preset that does not exist in V2.

If you are using .NET, take a look at these samples to get started with the v3 API and the Audio analyzer preset using a Transform.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/AudioAnalytics/AudioAnalyzer

Let me know if you have further questions. Details on the Audio analyzer preset can be found in the docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-video-audio-files-concept

Comment: Thank you @johndeu. I will try migrating it to v3 . I hope there wont be much code changes.